# Jquery 1.10.1 click on (Event delegation issue)

Tags: jquery, class, click, jsfiddle

Please take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8KDv/3/).  Based on a click, an appended class is added to div.  I'm trying to click based on the class and get a response.  Your help is greatly appreciate!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var count = 0;
    $("#more_time").click(function () {
        count += 1;

        $("#list_times").append($("#more_time").text() + " - <span id='remove_" + count + "' class='remove' style='cursor:pointer; '>(remove)</span><br>");
    });

    $(".remove").on("click", function () {
        alert("Hello");
    });

});
```

**html**

```
<div id="more_time">Weekdays 7:00am - 9:00am - More Time</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="list_times"></div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not just in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like **event delegation** is your friend here.

Instead of binding the event to the class

```
$('.remove').on('click', function {  // some code});
```

Delegate the event to its static parent

```
$('#list_times').on('click', '.remove', function {  // some code});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8KDv/7/)**

Comment: +1 for there being an explanation

Comment: That's awesome!  New issue...now the additions I need to remove found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/J8KDv/9/

Comment: Encase your span in a container.. And then try using `closest` to target the div container.. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/J8KDv/10/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.remove` binding code to the [delegated syntax](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

```
$("#list_times").on("click", '.remove', function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/J8KDv/6/